# Slow update query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am having a problem with updating a table from a select statement... Here is the command:

```
UPDATE CrashReport SET STATUS = '2' WHERE id IN (
    SELECT report_id 
    FROM CrashInfo 
    WHERE info_title LIKE 'STACK_TRACE_ID'
    AND info_value IN (
        SELECT info_value
        FROM CrashInfo
        WHERE report_id = **report_id**
        AND info_title = 'STACK_TRACE_ID'
    )
)
```

The parameter that I am passing to this query will be the report_id that is in the sub sub query... The select takes *0.113* seconds to execute all alone, but the update query takes a total of *4.868* seconds to execute. Is it because the update query will execute the select statement on every single row of the table? How can I make this faster?

Thank you

Comment: The last select returns only 1 value??

Comment: Yes the last query returns 1 value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SET @myVal = (
    SELECT info_value
    FROM CrashInfo
    WHERE report_id = **report_id**
    AND info_title = 'STACK_TRACE_ID');

UPDATE CrashReport SET STATUS = '2' WHERE id IN (
SELECT report_id 
FROM CrashInfo 
WHERE info_title LIKE 'STACK_TRACE_ID'
AND info_value IN (@myVal)
)
```

Comment: It worked! I am not sure this solution is super clean but it is faster! Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad to help...feel free to ask ;)

Answer (score 0):

`IN` can sometimes be slow in MySQL.  You can rephrase the query using `join`s (even in an `update`):

```
UPDATE CrashReport cr join
       (SELECT report_id 
        FROM CrashInfo ci join
             info_value iv
             on report_id = **report_id** AND
                info_title = 'STACK_TRACE_ID'
       ) cir
       on cr.id = cir.id
    SET cr.STATUS = '2';
```

As I see this, it looks like the join condition between `CrashInfo` and `info_value` is missing.  Should there be some field equal to each other in these two tables?  That would explain the poor performance.

Comment: The table CrashReport contains an id,
The table CrashInfo contains an id, a report_id, a title, a value